# Get App.config as parameter on the init application method

Tags: c#, app-config

My application is using App.config to get configuration. 
I created new project and i want to use the same App.config file in this new project. 
I want to send the file (can be location path of the App.config file) to the init of the new project (the sender is the original application that i wrote)

How can i send the App.config to the new project ?
Is it possible to load the App.config dynamically as a parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the full requirement, but why don't you just "add an existing Item" in the Solution-Explorer and in the upcomming Window you click "Add as link"?

Comment: i can't add an exusting item because this item is dynamic and need to be added from other process to the dll

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Am I correct with the assumption that you're talking about a deployed system which can be restarted with a new App.config?

So i.e. example your Appliacation listens to "new Versions" and as soon as it get's one, it should restart with the new Version of the App.config?